# Issue with invoking lambda from another lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have 2 Lambda functions that I would like to call directly not through API Gateway. Lambda function A is Calling Lambda B along with queryStringParameters. For some reasons I'm getting this error

> { UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'queryStringParameters' found in params

This is my Lambda A function

```
    var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new aws.Lambda({
  region: 'eu-central-1'
});    
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
var params = {
      FunctionName: "function-getStats", 
      InvocationType: "RequestResponse", 
      LogType: "Tail", 
      "queryStringParameters" : { "fn" : "latest_no" }
     };
     lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
       else     console.log(data);           // successful response
     });
};
```

Which is calling Lambda B as below

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-central-1'});
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var fn = event["queryStringParameters"]['fn'];
...
..


//If successful return the following response
     console.log("Success", items);
                callback(null, {
                    'statusCode': '200',
                    'body': JSON.stringify(items),
                    'headers': {
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"

                    },
                    'isBase64Encoded': false
                });
```

Can someone please advise how to fix this?

Comment: The issue is with Lambda A, Lambda B is running fine from Test or through API gateway. I'm not sure why it couldn't find queryStringParameters

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone got the same issue.  here's the approach I did

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new aws.Lambda({
  region: 'eu-central-1'
});    
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    event.queryStringParameters= {"fn" : "latest_no" };
var params = {
      FunctionName: "function-getStats", 
      InvocationType: "RequestResponse", 
      LogType: "Tail", 
      Payload: JSON.stringify(event, null, 2), 

     };
     lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
       else     console.log(data);           // successful response
     });
};
```